# Jekyll bootstrap use fixed categories list

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-bootstrap

Categories are "lightweight" in Jekyll, that is, rather than being fixed in a config file or list somewhere, they are created from scraping the YAML front matter from all the posts (and pages?).

I kind of don't like that because I also want to include descriptions for categories.  So that my page will look basically like (pretend has reasonable HTML/CSS)

> #### General
>
> For stuff
>
> #### Personal
>
> For boring stuff

I would like to specify the descriptions fixed somewhere.  I'm figuring out how to hack that with Jekyll bootstrap using their custom categories but the liquid is a bit dense so we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply specify the descriptions in the `_config.yml`. Ofc if you use categories in your post for which you do not have a description, there will be no text.

Comment: As a hash map or something?  When iterating over `site.categories` I'd have to access it out of config somehow by the category.

Comment: Yes ofc as a map, use your category names as keys and the descriptions as values.